# Replace N digit numbers in a sentence with specific strings for different values of N

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a bunch of strings in a pandas dataframe that contain numbers in them. I could the riun the below code and replace them all

```
df.feature_col = df.feature_col.str.replace('\d+', ' NUM ')
```

But what I need to do is replace any 10 digit number with a string like `masked_id`, any 16 digit numbers with `account_number`, or any three-digit numbers with yet another string, and so on.

How do I go about doing this?

PS: since my data size is less, a less optimal way is also good enough for me.

Comment: `'\d{10}'` instead of `'\d+'`?

Comment: You must do those in the correct order, because of course a check for 3-digit numbers will happily match a 16-digit number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is `replace` with option `regex=True` with a dictionary. You can also use somewhat more relaxed match
patterns (in order) than Tim's:

```
# test data
df = pd.DataFrame({'feature_col':['this has 1234567', 
                                  'this has 1234', 
                                  'this has 123',
                                  'this has none']})

# pattern in decreasing length order
# these of course would replace '12345' with 'ID45' :-)
df['feature_col'] = df.feature_col.replace({'\d{7}': 'ID7',
                                            '\d{4}': 'ID4',   
                                            '\d{3}': 'ID3'}, 
                                           regex=True)
```

Output:

```
     feature_col
0   this has ID7
1   this has ID4
2   this has ID3
3  this has none
```

Comment: One caveat to this answer. Just realized we can't have numbers in the replacement string. I am matching up to single-digit numbers and `'ID7'` becomes `'IDID1'` by the end

Answer (score 2):

You could do a series of replacements, one for each length of number:

```py
df.feature_col = df.feature_col.str.replace(r'\b\d{3}\b', ' 3mask ')
df.feature_col = df.feature_col.str.replace(r'\b\d{10}\b', masked_id)
df.feature_col = df.feature_col.str.replace(r'\b\d{16}\b', account_number)
```